# Would it help to ask lots of questions during Ramadan?

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette

Given the massive spike in traffic we can expect to see during the upcoming Ramadan, I'm thinking it would help jump-start the site we ask lots of questions during Ramadan.

**Question**: Would it help to ask lots of questions during Ramadan?

On some other sites there's a [maximum of 50 questions per 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/351283):

> Actually... 50/month is kinda insane. There are other people trying to use these websites too ya know. -- [Shog9 ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89230/351283)

Shog9 has a fair point, and I don't want to drown out other users from asking questions.  However, it's less than two per day, which doesn't seem all that much.  I think I could reach that amount.

I've saved a few questions on my computer (I could just copy/paste them into the question box).  Reading the Qur'an (which is encouraged during Ramadan in particular) will probably prompt more.  And I consider them good deeds, which are also good to do during Ramadan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ramadan challenge**.  Aiming for 50 questions during Ramadan.  *I'm done now.*

I'm out of questions, and need to do other things.  But I got 50+ questions in.  It became a bit of a bookkeeping nightmare trying to juggle everything.

I'm not sure if doing this (asking them in a batch during Ramadan) achieved anything more than just asking them naturally.  **Without a clear "this achieved XYZ", I don't think it would be worthwhile repeating this.**

I think I contributed to this spike in the number of weekly questions though:

[image]

And we did momentarily break [15 questions per day](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3003/17163)!

---

Thoughts during the process:

- I seem to be generating a lot of unanswered questions, but I expect they'll be answered over time anyway.  So I'm only slightly concerned about this.
- There's some users who consistently write high-quality answers, which is great except it can obstruct less-established users from having a go.  I think asking questions rapidly may help with this problem (and we need a [middle class](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3020/17163) who can vote on posts, help moderate the site, and vote in elections).
- Part of the aim of this is to keep effortful questions on the front page during Ramadan, ideally encouraging others to post questions with comparable effort, and making people think twice before posting no-effort posts.  I'm not sure if I had any effect.
- Part of the aim is to maintain an active front page throughout Ramadan.

---

27 May 2017

1. [Could it be beneficial to leave Islam and convert back with a clean slate?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40048/17163) [accepted answer]
2. [When does someone stop being an orphan?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40055/17163) [accepted answer]

28 May 2017

3. [Which prominent Sunni scholars say music is not haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40087/17163)
4. [Were there non-Imam Prophets as per Shia Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40096/17163) [accepted answer]
5. [Is the minimum marriage age for males 12 and females 9 in the Hanafi fiqh?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40104/17163) [accepted answer]

29 May 2017

6. [If one shortens prayer for travel during Ramadan, must they also not fast?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40118/17163)
7. [Does halal certification imply food is halal insofar as being a food?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40128/17163)

30 May 2017

8. [How is the Shia prostration of thanksgiving performed?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40158/17163)
9. [How can we determine if a wali is refusing marriage to a man whose religious commitment and character are good?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40163/17163)
10. [What is the significance of slitting the ears of cattle in Qur'an 4:119?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40174/17163) [accepted answer]

31 May 2017

11. [Is the practice of "marrying the Qur'an" allowed?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40192/17163)
12. [How do female Islam educators encourage women to wear hijab?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40205/17163)

1 June 2017

13. [Which scholars claimed Buddha was a messenger of God?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40234/17163)
14. [If sleeping invalidates wudu, why are we encouraged to do wudu before sleeping?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40247/17163) [accepted answer]
15. [What am I expected to do when people ask me to pray for them?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40262/17163) [accepted answer]

2 June 2017

16. [Step 1. Istikharah. Step 2. "Will you marry me?" Step 3. "No." Is this how it's meant to work?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40275/17163)
17. [How do Shias perform the taslim (final salam) in prayer?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40281/17163)
18. [Is the reward for observing hijab in Iran the same as for observing hijab in Australia?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40300/17163) [accepted answer]

3 June 2017

19. [Does obeying the "law of the land" extend to extraterritorial jurisdiction?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40316/17163)
20. [Who uses "sharia" as a synonym for "fiqh" or "din"?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40333/17163)

4 June 2017

21. [If Allah is neither "He" nor "She", why is it so important to call Him "He"?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40349/17163) [accepted answer]
22. [Does the Arabic in Qur'an 4:16 "...the two who commit it..." necessarily refer to two men?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40359/17163) [accepted answer]

5 June 2017

23. [Does Qur'an 6:26 imply that someone kept away from Islam is blameless?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40385/17163)
24. [If those who have gone astray will not harm the guided (Qur'an 5:105), why were many Prophets harmed?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40389/17163) [accepted answer]
25. [Why do some translations of Qur'an 79:30 talk about the Earth being egg-shaped?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40391/17163) [accepted answer]
26. [Does Qur'an 5:48 imply that Allah wants Jews to follow the Torah and Christians to follow the Gospel, instead of the Qur'an?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40402/17163) [accepted answer]

6 June 2017

27. [If a Muslim friend started drinking alcohol in front of me, how can I appropriately react?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40414/17163) [accepted answer]
28. [If homosexuality should result in execution, why is it not listed in ahadith as a reason to kill someone?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40415/17163) [accepted answer]
29. [How can Prophet Isa return to Earth without violating Prophet Muhammad being the last Prophet?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40428/17163) [accepted answer]

7 June 2017

30. [When marital problems arise, how is arbitration as per Qur'an 4:35 conducted?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40441/17163) [accepted answer]
31. [In Shia Islam, how is the ruling forbidding fasting while travelling arrived at?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40461/17163)

8 June 2017

32. [Is the translation of Qur'an 4:40 "If there be a good deed, He will repay twofold" inaccurate?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40476/17163) [accepted answer]
33. [Does Qur'an 4:3 forbid marrying more than four wives?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40481/17163) [accepted answer]
34. [If a Muslim woman were beaten by her husband who believes his actions are Sharia compliant, how can she rectify the situation?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40482/17163) [accepted answer]
35. [Are any parts of the Bible generally accepted as the authentic word of Allah?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40501/17163)

9 June 2017

36. [Who is Prophet Muhammad's enemy mentioned in Qur'an 6:112?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40509/17163) [accepted answer]
37. [What is an example of how a contextualist scholar applies the Qur'an in different ways according to context?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40518/17163) [accepted answer]
38. [Is it haram for a husband to get his 13 or 14-year-old wife pregnant?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40526/17163)
39. [How is Qur'an 4:93 (which forbids killing a believer) compatible with the death penalty?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40531/17163)

10 June 2017

40. [How is Qur'an 6:146, where Jews are prohibited from certain foods, compatible with "no bearer of burdens will bear the burden of another"?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40544/17163) [accepted answer]
41. [Does the word "infidel" have any significance in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40552/17163)
42. [Who went around the Kabah naked before Prophet Muhammad forbade it?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40565/17163) [accepted answer]
43. [Can people in heaven and hell ordinarily communicate with one another?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40567/17163) [accepted answer]

11 June 2017

44. [Is there an authentic hadith to the effect of "If Fatima suffers, I also suffer. Don't you ever marry anyone but Fatima"?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40583/17163) [accepted answer]
45. [According to scholars who view transgenderism as haram, what should a post-operative transsexual do?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40611/17163)
46. [What does "doubled and multiplied" means in the context of usury in Qur'an 3:130?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40612/17163)

12 June 2017

47. [What does the "Taqlid Period, after the formation of Madhabs and the closing of the gate of ijtihad" refer to?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40624/17163) [accepted answer]
48. [Does Qur'an 23:6 talk about "wives" or "spouses" in إِلَّا عَلَىٰ أَزْوَاجِهِمْ?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40625/17163) [accepted answer]

13 June 2017

49. [What is an example of how biological evolution is presented in an Islamic school textbook?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40655/17163)

14 June 2017

50. [Are things mentioned with higher frequently in the Qur'an considered more important?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40680/17163)
51. [What is an example of how Fazlur Rahman emphasized contextualized Qur'anic meanings in relation to ratio legis?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40700/17163)
52. [Can a wife get a divorce if she is incapable of returning the mahr?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40708/17163)

15 June 2017

(?!  I lost track of dates here.)

16 June 2017

53. [A husband made a list of demands which prompted his wife to leave Islam; are all of them legally acceptable?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40727/17163)
54. [Does Sahih Muslim contain a hadith to the effect of "has Allah not rendered for you the isha prayer in congregation equal to hajj"?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40734/17163) [accepted answer]
55. [Is there an authentic hadith where a woman is forbidden from leaving the house while her father dies, but they're forgiven for her obedience?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40737/17163)
56. [Which classical Hanafis believed anal intercourse is allowed in paradise?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40750/17163) [accepted answer]

17 June 2016

57. [Is there a relationship between the Arabic terms عائشة‎ (A'isha) and صلاة العشاء (isha prayer)?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40767/17163) [accepted answer]
58. [Does Aisha witnessing her father's migration to Abyssinia imply she could not have consummated her marriage at age 9?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40778/17163)
59. [How do we know the Battle of Uhud was fought on Saturday, March 23, 625?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40783/17163)

18 June 2017

60. [What is the basic process of becoming an imam (prayer leader) at a local mosque?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40801/17163) [accepted answer]
61. [Could divorce by feigning apostasy be used to escape a violent husband?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40803/17163) [accepted answer]
62. [Can an arbitrator for domestic disputes in Qur'an 4:35 be a non-Muslim?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40816/17163) [accepted answer]

(I won't continue updating this post; expect it to be out of date.)

Comment: It been 10 days into Ramadan and we already got 26. We probably would end up getting way over 50.

Comment: It's possible I might simply run out of questions though.  (:  [You can probably tell which part of the Qur'an I'm up to though.]

Comment: Goal over-achieved was earlier than end of Ramadan. Excellent effort, and it certainly helped keep the site going.

Answer (score 1):

I'm all for it, the historical data supports it and we just might acquire some very knowledgeable users in the process.

The quality of the questions matters. Quantity not so much in my opinion.

We just need to reinforce a few SE behaviors:

- try to make the questions interesting, relevant and objective. The questions sandbox will help in that regard
- expect lots of "noisy" new users. The community will have to be patient with them
- it might be worth cleaning up some of the Ramadan-related posts that already exist to enhance the perceived quality of the site