# Getting closer to the 10 questions per day mark!

Tags: discussion, questions

The 10 questions per day mark is important for site graduation:

> When a site starts to consistently receive 10 questions/day, we’ll consider it for graduation. -- [Ana ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/351283), 2015

*We're getting close to this mark!*

1. Questions per day:

   ```
   Date (May 2017):  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
   No. Questions:    5  7  9  7 14 10  9 11 10  9 15  6 13 12 10 10 13 16 10  8
   ```
2. Google Analytics shows we just asked 84 questions in the week of Monday May 8, 2017, more than 10 per day on average.  In fact, this rate of incoming questions hasn't happened since the start of Islam.SE back in 2012.

   [image]
3. On [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14922/islam), we're getting very close to 10 questions per day:

   [image]

And we're not even at the [Ramadan spike](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2947/17163) yet.  I posted about this previously here: [The number of questions/answers and upvotes/downvotes per day](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1865/17163)

---

*Update*:  Area 51 got bumped to the 10 questions per day mark:

[image]

*Update* (21 May 2017): Still over the 10 questions per day mark!:

[image]

*Update* (8 June 2017): I don't think we're yet to drop below 10 questions per day since we hit it.  In fact, during Ramadan, we just hit 15 questions per day!:

[image]

Extending the above plot:

[image]